# Resizing text input inside navbar with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following navbar at the top of my page (heavily copied from a bootstrap 3 example) - you can ignore the Django template code:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
     <div class="container-fluid">
         <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand plain" href="{% url 'home' %}">Miniquad Maps</a>
         </div>

      <form method="POST" action="{% url 'spot_search' %}" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
             <div class="form-group">
                 <input id="spotsearch" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search spots" name="spotsearch">
             </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search
             </button>
             {% csrf_token %}
         </form>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

I am trying to figure out how to resize the search input (the one with `id="spotsearch"`). I would like to make it much wider, and I have tried many things, but the element seems to be constrained by something else (some bootstrap class no doubt, but I have not been able to figure out which one).

I have tried using `.col-size-*` in various places (among other things), but nothing seems to affect the input's width.

What am I missing here? Any suggestions as to   how to resize the input, or where to look for good information on form sizing would be appreciated (I have read through the bootstrap docs on forms, but this has not been helpful so far in this respect).

Here is an example of the navbar: https://jsfiddle.net/38apotau/
I would like to resize the input to be at least twice the size it is in that example.

Comment: Please get a working code somewhere online so we can test it in browser. The question seem a bit generic.

Comment: @Narxx I added an example. I agree that the question is too generic. I am very new to web development, and am still in the stage where it is hard to even know what questions to ask/search for when I get stuck. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: The width of the element is set to `width: auto` by bootstrap, giving the class hierarchy you have set. You could override the input's width by giving it a specific pixel size: `#spotsearch { width: 350px; }`

Comment: @Narxx Ughhhh...That is the first thing that I tried, but I tried it with a percentage, which didn't work. I thought I tried it with a specific pixel size too, but I must not have. If you post this comment as an answer I will certainly accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the element is set to `width: auto` by bootstrap, giving the class hierarchy you have set.

You could override the input's width by giving it a specific pixel size:

`#spotsearch { width: 350px; }`